# How to reuse a instance without a frame in Java?

Tags: java

I use [browscap-java](https://github.com/blueconic/browscap-java) in my project. But the initial loading time is too long.

```
final UserAgentParser parser = new UserAgentService().loadParser();
```

The loading code costs about 22058ms.

Here is my code:

```
 public String[] getAgentInfo() {
    final UserAgentParser parser;
    try {
        parser = new UserAgentService().loadParser();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    final String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36";
    final Capabilities capabilities = parser.parse(userAgent);
    final String[] agentInfo = new String[6];

    agentInfo[0] = capabilities.getBrowser();
    agentInfo[1] = capabilities.getBrowserType();
    agentInfo[2] = capabilities.getBrowserMajorVersion();
    agentInfo[3] = capabilities.getDeviceType();
    agentInfo[4] = capabilities.getPlatform();
    agentInfo[5] = capabilities.getPlatformVersion();

    return agentInfo;
}
```

each time I use this function will initialize the `parser`. But the `parser` is changeless, so I want to know how to reuse the `parser`, make the `parser` only initialize at the first time.

PS: the code is for java web.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize/build your parser outside this method and pass it as an argument. This will give you the flexibility to initialize the parser once and call this method multiple times by passing already initialized parser.

```
public UserAgentParser createUserAgentParser() {
    final UserAgentParser parser;
    try {
        parser = new UserAgentService().loadParser();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return parser;
 }

 public String[] getAgentInfo(final UserAgentParser parser) {

    final String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36";
    final Capabilities capabilities = parser.parse(userAgent);
    final String[] agentInfo = new String[6];

    agentInfo[0] = capabilities.getBrowser();
    agentInfo[1] = capabilities.getBrowserType();
    agentInfo[2] = capabilities.getBrowserMajorVersion();
    agentInfo[3] = capabilities.getDeviceType();
    agentInfo[4] = capabilities.getPlatform();
    agentInfo[5] = capabilities.getPlatformVersion();

    return agentInfo;
}
```